# Range penalty for guns

Tags: range, game-physics

I'd like to know if anyone has a formula for range penalty that takes into account that the horizontal inaccuracy involves straight trig but the vertical inaccuracy involves ballistic inaccuracy ( calculating for the falloff effects of gravity) AND trig.

Comment: Have you tried using the distance from the current position of the bullet to the position where the bullet was fired? I doubt you need more accuracy.

Comment: Wouldn't you just calculate whether the bullet's trajectory actually intersects the target's trajectory? What would "penalty" mean here?

Comment: The amount of ballistic variance that 1 degree of inaccuracy causes on arced fire is greater at greater ranges. I.e., if you were to exclusively model inaccuracy of lobbing the bullet like a cannonball, how would accuracy vary by distance?

Comment: @DaveEdelhart I guess I'm just not grasping what 1 degree of inaccuracy refers to here. With idealized physics, whether a projectile collides with a stationary or constant velocity target is a deterministic outcome. Once you know a projectile's current position and velocity (assuming it is only experiencing gravity), you can tell whether or not it passes through a given point at a given time. The accuracy doesn't degrade as the projectile is flying through the air (unless there are other fluctuating forces acting on it). What is the random variable here?